How to table.remove() nested elements in lua?
a={ {11,22,33} }

How to remove a[1][1] aka 11 with table.remove() so it becomes a={ {22,33} }?
In the pico8 lua it is del(a[1],a[1][1])
I have no idea what table.remove(a[1],a[1][1]) is doing, it seems to do nothing. I don't understand how you would create del() in vanilla lua.
I suppose you can a[1][1]=nil and then apply some sorting algorithm, but I would hope I'm just missing the simpler solution.

table.remove (a[1], 1)

Do not thank.
